# Android moving 'windows'

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android and I'm need a little help understanding how to move from one window to another. I know i use `setContentView(R.layout.main)` to load an xml layout file, but how do i swap to another layout file? I assume i would use an onClick method on a button and change `setContentView(R.layout.other_layout)`, but would doing all this inside my main activity make my code cluttered? I could end up having 10000+ LOC easily. Can someone explain the correct way to do this please. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intents allow us to call another activity from our present activity. For example our current activity is Act1 and we want to move to another activity, Act2. this can be done as:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Act1.this, Act2.class);
startactivity(i);
```

Refer http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html for more information on intents and activity.

Another option is to call setContentView() 2nd time to change the layout.

Answer (score 1):

You use Intents to launch other Activities.

In your current Activity (i.e. window), you can do the following code to launch a new Activity

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, NewActivityName.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: `this` refers to the current `Activity` from which you want to launch the second `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

You should create [Activities](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html). Activity is equivalent to window/frame concept on desktop. Each activity should have a goal towards user interaction, ie. taking inputs and showing output. In your case create two activies, and both of them should have their own layour XML and a call to `setContentView()` within `onCreate()`.

On button click use [startActivity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29) to invoke a new one. Keep in mind that these activities are stacked top of one another.

Answer (score 0):

A visible screen in Android is represented by an Activity. So instead of loading a different layout file into the same activity, you simple create a new activity with it's own layout and java file. 
In order to call this second activity from the first one, or to communicate between activities in general android uses so called **Intents**.
Just look [that chapter](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html) up in Android's Dev-Gui.